# process and display bold/italics characters from a file

Tags: java, android

Can anyone suggest how can I read and display bold/italics characters from a file in java/android. I have some italics characters which I am reading from a file under assets and then displaying those characters in a TextView. Once I get the contents in a string, the bold/italics goes off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Plain text files**

You can achieve by adding HTML tags to your text as this

```
This text is <i>italic</i> <b>bold</b>
<u>underlined</u> <b><i><u>bold italic underlined</u></b></i>
```

and then you can use the [HTML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class that processes HTML strings into displayable styled text.

```
// textString is the String after you retrieve it from the file
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textString));
```

**Microsoft Word or Excel files**

I didn't try it myself but you can look at the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library.

Comment: What if my file already has styled text and I am extracting the string from the file and displaying it in TextView? In your case you are styling the text in TextView using Html tags.

Comment: You mean you don't have a plain text file and that you have word processed one for example (doc, docx)?

Comment: I have an excel file from which I am extracting text. And then I put that text into a textview. Now if the file has some text underlined, its does not show that way in textview. All the underline goes off and the text appears as normal.